# darknet: ./src/utils.c:325: error: Assertion `0' failed (YOLO-v4) Google colab

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

I try to use Google Colab for training YOLO_v4 on my own data set and met the next error:

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/blas_kernels.cu : () : line: 841 : build time: Oct  9 2020 - 12:04:13 

 CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device: File exists
darknet: ./src/utils.c:325: error: Assertion `0' failed.
CPU times: user 58 ms, sys: 12.4 ms, total: 70.4 ms
Wall time: 15.4 s
```

I've checked my code but can't find mistake.
Then I ran the Google Colab notebook with example I used(https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbzkKcACQPzLXuBYH7KPOh73Ko8xdUPn#scrollTo=6miYFbvExqMd). When I execute the cell:

```
%%time
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg -dont_show -map #./backup/custom-yolov4-detector_last.weights
#If you get CUDA out of memory adjust subdivisions above!
#adjust max batches down for shorter training above
```

this error appears sometimes do not.
I'm so confused...
I think that it is somehow related to availability or type of GPU that I am connected.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check this link and download darknet like what is here[enter link description here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/2117)

then create a yolov4.conf file and config it base on your number of class labels. you can find an example of this configuration here:[enter link description here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/2263)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.